# What is the spin effect of gravitational waveforms?

Tags: gravity, gravitational-waves

How can we evaluate the effect of the spin of a GW source on a waveform? That is, how the spin of a rotating body enters in the gravitational wave amplitude/frequency/phase?

Comment: Are you asking about binaries, involving spinning objects, or spinning objects generating their own gravitational waves?

Comment: @TimRias Generally speaking, both...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question. If either component of a binary is spinning this will in general affect all aspects of the gravitational waveforms produced including amplitudes, phases, and frequencies. Here I will highlight just two major effects:

### Precession

If the spins of the components are not aligned with the orbital angular momentum of the orbital plane, then this will cause the orbital plane to precess around the total angular momentum of the system. The effect of this on the waveform, is that the amplitude gets a characteristic modulation related to the precession.

### The ``Hangup'' effect

How closely a binary can (quasi)-stably  orbit each other depends on the effective spin (a mass-weighted combination of the projections of the spins on the orbital angular momentum). Highly aligned binaries (i.e. large effective spin) can achieve closer orbits with higher orbital frequencies than anti-aligned (negative effective spin) binaries. The main effect of this on the waveform is that aligned spin binaries will have waveforms that peak at higher frequencies and will achieve a larger amplitude at this peak than a non-spinning binary with the same masses.

This is some times called the ``hang-up'' effect, and plays an important role in assuring that the result of a binary merger never can produce black hole with spin larger than the maximum value.